# Custom RTMP server

Tags: jitsi

I'm trying to set up JaaS to send RTMP to a custom RTMP server in our company, but I just can't find the way to inform the url.
I saw that startRecording command has rtmpStreamKey and rtmpBroadcastID options, but what about the url, how do I inform it ?

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Perhaps this is a language issue, but can you explain better what you mean by "inform" in the context of this question, as in "...find the way to INFORM the url." Do you mean "find", perhaps, or "publish", or something else?

Answer (score 1):

RTMP urls look like: `rtmp://server.domain.com/live/1234ABCDE`. The exact formatting depends on the RTMP service you're sending to. Some will split the key (everything after the last `/`) into a separate value, but they'll need to be combined.

Jitsi takes the whole server+key URL as a stream key. See this example guide for sending to Stream9: https://support.screen9.com/kb/faq.php?id=262

Broadcast ID is optional, depending on the RTMP service

Comment: I'm depending on a FW rule to test this. ASAI get the rule, I'll tell you the result. Thanks!